# How to share data between a TThread in a DLL and the main thread?

Tags: multithreading, dll, c++builder

I'm writing a DLL in C++Builder XE6, that creates a separate thread (derived from TThread) to retrieve JSON data from a REST server every X seconds (using TIdHTTP), and parse the JSON data.

The thread fills a simple struct (no dynamically allocated data) with the parsed JSON data in the `Execute()` method of the thread:

```
typedef struct
{
    char MyString[40 + 1];
    double MyDouble;
    bool MyBool;
} TMyStruct;
```

The thread should store the struct in a list, for example a `std::vector`:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<TMyStruct> MyList;
```

The thread will add a TMyStruct to the list:

```
TMyStruct Data;
...
MyList.push_back(Data);
```

The list will be guarded by a `TCriticalSection` to prevent data corruption.

The DLL exports a function to retrieve a `TMyStruct` from `MyList`.

```
bool __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall GetMyStruct (int Index, TMyStruct* Data)
{
    ...
}
```

Only thing is, I don't know where to put `MyList`...

If I make `MyList` a global variable, it is located in the main thread's memory and `GetMyStruct()` can access it directly. How does the thread access `MyList`?

If I make `MyList` a member of the `TThread`-derived class, it is located in the thread's memory and the thread can access it directly. How does `GetMyStruct()` access `MyList`?

What is the best/prefered/common way to store `MyList` and access it in a different thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I make `MyList` a global variable, it is located in the main thread's memory and `GetMyStruct()` can access it directly. How does the thread access `MyList`?

The exact same way.  All threads in a process can freely access global variables within that process.  For example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <System.SyncObjs.hpp>

typedef struct
{
    char MyString[40 + 1];
    double MyDouble;
    bool MyBool;
} TMyStruct;

std::vector<TMyStruct> MyList;
TCriticalSection *Lock = NULL; // why not std::mutex instead?

class TMyThread : public TThread
{
    ...
};
TMyThread *Thread = NULL;

...

void __fastcall TMyThread::Execute()
{
    TMyStruct Data;
    ...
    Lock->Enter();
    try {
        MyList.push_back(Data);
    }
    __finally {
        Lock->Leave();
    }
    ...
}

...

void __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall StartThread ()
{
    Lock = new TCriticalSection;
    Thread = new TMyThread;
}

void __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall StopThread ()
{
    if (Thread) {
        Thread->Terminate();
        Thread->WaitFor();
        delete Thread;
        Thread = NULL;
    }
    if (Lock) {
        delete Lock;
        Lock = NULL;
    }
}

bool __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall GetMyStruct (int Index, TMyStruct* Data)
{
    if (!(Lock && Thread)) return false;

    Lock->Enter();
    try {
        *Data = MyList[Index];
    }
    __finally {
        Lock->Leave();
    }

    return true;
}
```

> If I make `MyList` a member of the `TThread`-derived class, it is located in the thread's memory and the thread can access it directly. How does `GetMyStruct()` access `MyList`?

By accessing it via a pointer to the thread object.  For example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <System.SyncObjs.hpp>

typedef struct
{
    char MyString[40 + 1];
    double MyDouble;
    bool MyBool;
} TMyStruct;

class TMyThread : public TThread
{
protected:
    void __fastcall Execute();
public:
    __fastcall TMyThread();
    __fastcall ~TMyThread();

    std::vector<TMyStruct> MyList;
    TCriticalSection *Lock;
};

TMyThread *Thread = NULL;

...

__fastcall TMyThread::TMyThread()
    : TThread(false)
{
    Lock = new TCriticalSection;
}

__fastcall TMyThread::~TMyThread()
{
    delete Lock;
}

void __fastcall TMyThread::Execute()
{
    TMyStruct Data;
    ...
    Lock->Enter();
    try {
        MyList.push_back(Data);
    }
    __finally {
        Lock->Leave();
    }
    ...
}

void __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall StartThread ()
{
    Thread = new TMyThread;
}

void __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall StopThread ()
{
    if (Thread) {
        Thread->Terminate();
        Thread->WaitFor();
        delete Thread;
        Thread = NULL;
    }
}

bool __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall GetMyStruct (int Index, TMyStruct* Data)
{
    if (!Thread) return false;

    Thread->Lock->Enter();
    try {
        *Data = Thread->MyList[Index];
    }
    __finally {
        Thread->Lock->Leave();
    }

    return true;
}
```

> What is the best/prefered/common way to store `MyList` and access it in a different thread?

That is entirely up to you to decide, based on your particular needs and project design.

Comment: Sometimes, I tend to overthink things... Thanks for your help, Remy.

Comment: *"why not std::mutex instead?"* - That's what I wanted to use, but apparently there's no `std::mutex` in my version of C++Builder XE6. I did a file search on `mutex` in the 'include' folder, but didn't find it. The 'dinkumware' subfolder has `algorithm` ... `yvals.h`, but no `mutex`.

Comment: @MartinNijhoff `std::mutex` was introduced in C++11, in the `<mutex>` header. Only the Clang-based compilers support C++11, not the "classic" Borland compiler. So make sure your project is configured accordingly. The Clang C++11 compilers were first introduced in XE3.